# error occured when adding -static flag to gcc

Tags: c, gcc, static-libraries, x11

I'm trying to compile static-alone x11 executable apps(apt source x11-apps).

```
chenli% apt source x11-apps
chenli% cd x11-apps*/xclock
```

---

```
chenli% make -n   
......
echo "  CC      " Clock.o;gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I.    -Wall -Wpointer-arith -Wmissing-declarations -Wformat=2 -Wstrict-prototypes -Wmissing-prototypes -Wnested-externs -Wbad-function-cast -Wold-style-definition -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wunused -Wuninitialized -Wshadow -Wcast-q
ual -Wmissing-noreturn -Wmissing-format-attribute -Wredundant-decls -Werror=implicit -Werror=nonnull -Werror=init-self -Werror=main -Werror=missing-braces -Werror=sequence-point -Werror=return-type -Werror=trigraphs -Werror=array-bounds -Werror=write-strings -Werror=address -Werror
=int-to-pointer-cast -Werror=pointer-to-int-cast -fno-strict-aliasing -I/usr/include/uuid -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include/libpng16  -g -O2 -MT Clock.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/Clock.Tpo -c -o Clock.o Clock.c
mv -f .deps/Clock.Tpo .deps/Clock.Po
echo "  CC      " xclock.o;gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I.    -Wall -Wpointer-arith -Wmissing-declarations -Wformat=2 -Wstrict-prototypes -Wmissing-prototypes -Wnested-externs -Wbad-function-cast -Wold-style-definition -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wunused -Wuninitialized -Wshadow -Wcast-
qual -Wmissing-noreturn -Wmissing-format-attribute -Wredundant-decls -Werror=implicit -Werror=nonnull -Werror=init-self -Werror=main -Werror=missing-braces -Werror=sequence-point -Werror=return-type -Werror=trigraphs -Werror=array-bounds -Werror=write-strings -Werror=address -Werro
r=int-to-pointer-cast -Werror=pointer-to-int-cast -fno-strict-aliasing -I/usr/include/uuid -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include/libpng16  -g -O2 -MT xclock.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/xclock.Tpo -c -o xclock.o xclock.c
mv -f .deps/xclock.Tpo .deps/xclock.Po
rm -f xclock
echo "  CCLD    " xclock;gcc -Wall -Wpointer-arith -Wmissing-declarations -Wformat=2 -Wstrict-prototypes -Wmissing-prototypes -Wnested-externs -Wbad-function-cast -Wold-style-definition -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wunused -Wuninitialized -Wshadow -Wcast-qual -Wmissing-noreturn -
Wmissing-format-attribute -Wredundant-decls -Werror=implicit -Werror=nonnull -Werror=init-self -Werror=main -Werror=missing-braces -Werror=sequence-point -Werror=return-type -Werror=trigraphs -Werror=array-bounds -Werror=write-strings -Werror=address -Werror=int-to-pointer-cast -We
rror=pointer-to-int-cast -fno-strict-aliasing -I/usr/include/uuid -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include/libpng16  -g -O2   -o xclock Clock.o xclock.o -lXaw7 -lXmu -lXt -lX11  -lXrender -lX11 -lXft -lxkbfile -lm 
make[2]: Leaving directory '/tmp/x11-apps-7.7+7/xclock'
make[1]: Leaving directory '/tmp/x11-apps-7.7+7/xclock'
```

The three gcc commands(from `make -n` work perfect and xclock runs successfully. But when I add `-static` to the last command:

```
chenli% ldd *.o              
Clock.o:
        not a dynamic executable
xclock.o:
        not a dynamic executable
chenli% gcc -Wall -Wpointer-arith -Wmissing-declarations -Wformat=2 -Wstrict-prototypes -Wmissing-prototypes -Wnested-externs -Wbad-function-cast -Wold-style-definition -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wunused -Wuninitialized -Wshadow -Wcast-qual -Wmissing-noreturn -Wmissing-format-attribute -Wredundant-decls -Werror=implicit -Werror=nonnull -Werror=init-self -Werror=main -Werror=missing-braces -Werror=sequence-point -Werror=return-type -Werror=trigraphs -Werror=array-bounds -Werror=write-strings -Werror=address -Werror=int-to-pointer-cast -Werror=pointer-to-int-cast -fno-strict-aliasing -I/usr/include/uuid -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include/libpng16  -g -O2   -o xclock Clock.o xclock.o -lXaw7 -lXmu -lXt -lX11  -lXrender -lX11 -lXft -lxkbfile -lm -static

......

(.text+0x60): undefined reference to `FcStrCmpIgnoreCase'
/usr/lib/gcc/sw_64sw6-sunway-linux-gnu/5.3.0/../../../sw_64-linux-gnu/libXft.a(xftstr.o): In function `_XftMatchSymbolic':
(.text+0x6c): undefined reference to `FcStrCmpIgnoreCase'
/usr/lib/gcc/sw_64sw6-sunway-linux-gnu/5.3.0/../../../sw_64-linux-gnu/libxkbfile.a(xkbbells.o): In function `XkbStdBell':
(.text+0x88): undefined reference to `XkbBell'
/usr/lib/gcc/sw_64sw6-sunway-linux-gnu/5.3.0/../../../sw_64-linux-gnu/libxkbfile.a(xkbbells.o): In function `XkbStdBell':
(.text+0x9c): undefined reference to `XkbBell'
/usr/lib/gcc/sw_64sw6-sunway-linux-gnu/5.3.0/../../../sw_64-linux-gnu/libxkbfile.a(xkbbells.o): In function `XkbStdBellEvent':
(.text+0x158): undefined reference to `XkbBellEvent'
/usr/lib/gcc/sw_64sw6-sunway-linux-gnu/5.3.0/../../../sw_64-linux-gnu/libxkbfile.a(xkbbells.o): In function `XkbStdBellEvent':
(.text+0x16c): undefined reference to `XkbBellEvent'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I have tried add more and more lib via `-lXXX` to fix some errors, but still have new undefined reference pop up.

I also debted the order of libs matters https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2013/07/09/library-order-in-static-linking and [Why does the order in which libraries are linked sometimes cause errors in GCC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45135/why-does-the-order-in-which-libraries-are-linked-sometimes-cause-errors-in-gcc)

But gcc works fine without `-static` and only have errors with `-static`.

How can I fix this problem and why `-static` cause such errors?

### UPDATE

I try to force gcc to use static libraries:

```
deepin@sw6a:~/chenli/xclock$ gcc -Wall -Wpointer-arith -Wmissing-declarations -Wformat=2 -Wstrict-prototypes -Wmissing-prototypes -Wnested-externs -Wbad-function-cast -Wold-style-definition -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wunused -Wuninitialized -Wshadow -Wcast-qual -Wmissing-noreturn -Wmissing-format-attribute -Wredundant-decls -Werror=implicit -Werror=nonnull -Werror=init-self -Werror=main -Werror=missing-braces -Werror=sequence-point -Werror=return-type -Werror=trigraphs -Werror=array-bounds -Werror=write-strings -Werror=address -Werror=int-to-pointer-cast -Werror=pointer-to-int-cast -fno-strict-aliasing -I/usr/include/uuid -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include/libpng16  -g -O2   -o xclock Clock.o xclock.o  -lXaw7  -lXmu -lXt -lX11  -l:libXrender.a -lX11 -lXft -lxkbfile -lm
```

But when it comes to some package like `Xaw7`:

```
chenli% gcc -I/usr/include/uuid -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include/libpng16  -g -O2   -o xclock Clock.o xclock.o /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXaw7.a -lXmu -lXt -lX11  -l:libXrender.a -lXft -l:libxkbfile.a -l:libm.a
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXaw7.a(libXaw7_la-Command.o): undefined reference to symbol 'XShapeQueryExtension'
/usr/bin/ld: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXext.so.6: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

It's really wired, why static library(libXaw7.a) report `undefined reference to symbol` error?

Comment: `-lXaw7 -lXmu -lXt -lX11  -lXrender -lX11 -lXft -lxkbfile` - you have to compile all shared libraries statically too. You can't statically link a shared library.

Comment: Ha, good luck finding (or compiling) static versions of all those libs...

Comment: Thanks for you tips, please take a look at my update

Comment: FYI: not all libraries are available as static. Also, `*.a` is not neccessary a static library.

Comment: _Also, *.a is not neccessary a static library._ hi @AndrejsCainikovs any more explainations?(I don't know it before)

Comment: Some libraries provide files for linking to dynamic libraries, where you have a static code, but in reality there's a dependency on dynamic counterpart. I'm just nitpicking.